# SOLIDWORKS ErrorCode:1722 CA:Register_DocMgrDLL

Tags: windows, installation, regsvr32, solidworks

I am trying to install Solidworks to windows machine, and I am able to install 25% (all of that Visual Studio 20xx redistributeable and MS SQL server). But after that I am getting error:

```
Error   Status  149 0   "Product:SOLIDWORKS ErrorCode:1722 CA:Register_DocMgrDLL.A48C1CF2_EBF8_48E8_ACAD_68CA04F776A2 Location:C:\Windows\system32\ Command:regsvr32 "regsvr32 “C:\Program Files\Common Files\SOLIDWORKS Shared\swdocumentmgr.dll" /s"
```

I am seeing it tries to call `regsvr32 “C:\Program Files\Common Files\SOLIDWORKS Shared\swdocumentmgr.dll` So I tried to look up that library, but I do not have even the folder `SOLIDWORKS Shared`. I am installing the Solidwork from `.iso` file (which windows create another drive for it), and from the directory from the driver I am calling `setup.exe`. It launches the wizards with all the selection of their products and in summary I choose the installation destination to another-second driver `D:\` (which I suppose should not be problem - I do not have enough space in `C:\` drive). And as said, it installs 25% of full installation. So how can I get the `SOLIDWORKS shared` folder with the `swdocumentmgr.dll` in it? Here is the part of the log with the error:

```
17:57:04    Error   Status  149 0   "Product:SOLIDWORKS ErrorCode:1722 CA:Register_DocMgrDLL.A48C1CF2_EBF8_48E8_ACAD_68CA04F776A2 Location:C:\Windows\system32\ Command:regsvr32 "regsvr32 “C:\Program Files\Common Files\SOLIDWORKS Shared\swdocumentmgr.dll" /s"
17:57:46    Warning Message 9   55200   "Dialog Shown: {0: Internal error: The Windows Installer for this product component did not run as expected: Register_DocMgrDLL.A48C1CF2_EBF8_48E8_ACAD_68CA04F776A2.: Contact Technical Support.}.  User selected: {1: 1}"
17:58:21    Info    Status  58  55803   "Received data from Installation Manager server (Script: {0: http://im.solidworks.com/2019/Connect.aspx?Release=20190-40500-1100-100&Debug=0&ini=0&osa=8192:0:2&lid=1033&app=I&cx=4097:6&cm=-1&lfr=&lfp=&lfv=}, Code: {1: 0}, Error: {2: }, File: {3: <none>})"
18:00:02    Error   Status  156 0   "***START DUMP OF WINDOWS INSTALLER DATA***"
...
```

Comment: You might check if the methods in the following article was helpful to you:https://hawkridgesys.com/kb/fixing-installation-error-register-docmgrdll

Comment: @SunnyQi no - I am missing the `swdocumentmgr.dll` library and in the article, they suppose I have it. I made another question here

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1595832/how-to-load-dll-with-regsvr32-in-cmd-in-win10